# How can I correctly size UITabBarController icons?

Tags: ios, swift, image, icons, uitabbarcontroller

I use `UITabBarController`. In landscape it is looking fine:

[image: working tab bar]

In portrait though the images are way too big:

[image: not working tab bar]

The images are within xcassets, 512px squared in size and use single scale.

I use `UITabBarViewController` like this:

```
let tabBarController = UITabBarController()
tabBarController.viewControllers = [Tab1Controller(), Tab2Controller()]
```

In the TabXControllers, I have:

```
title = "Tab X"
tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "Tab X")
```

UPDATE:

I am building for iOS 13, so the Apple HIG at https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/custom-icons/ is not valid in this case (“iOS 12 and Earlier”). I assume in iOS 13 the icons can be bigger than they could be in iOS 12. They get downscaled automatically (see first screenshot)
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I also had the same issue, and image insets worked perfectly

```
tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 85, left: 85, bottom: 85, right: 85)
```

Answer (score 2):

For iOS 12 and below:

Read Apple Documentation for [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/custom-icons/)

> **Tab Bar Icon Size**
>
> In portrait orientation, tab bar icons appear above tab titles. In
>   landscape orientation, the icons and titles appear side-by-side.
>   Depending on the device and orientation, the system displays either a
>   regular or compact tab bar. Your app should include custom tab bar
>   icons for both sizes.

**Target width and height (circular glyphs)**

```
Regular tab bars    Compact tab bars
75px × 75px (25pt × 25pt @3x)   54px × 54px (18pt × 18pt @3x)
50px × 50px (25pt × 25pt @2x)   36px × 36px (18pt × 18pt @2x)
```

**Target width and height (square glyphs)**

```
Regular tab bars    Compact tab bars
69px × 69px (23pt × 23pt @3x)   51px × 51px (17pt × 17pt @3x)
46px × 46px (23pt × 23pt @2x)   34px × 34px (17pt × 17pt @2x)
```

**For IOS 13 and Above**

In iOS 13 or later, prefer using [SF Symbols](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sf-symbols/overview/) to represent tasks and modes in your app. SF Symbols provides a set of over 1,500 consistent, highly configurable symbols you can use in your app. Also you can create Custom SFSymbols. According to Apple

> If you need a symbol that isn't provided by SF Symbols, you can create
>   your own. The SF Symbols app lets you export a symbol as a template in
>   a reusable, vector-based file format. To create a custom symbol,
>   export an SF symbol that's similar to the design you want and modify
>   the template using a vector-editing tool like Sketch or Illustrator

Comment: Interesting. So the icons have to have a certain size when used in portrait but not in landscape?

Comment: I just saw, the guidelines you linked are only valid for iOS 12 and below. I assume in iOS 13 the behavior has changed, that’s why the landscape version is working even though the icons are 512px in size. The question remains: why doesn’t it work in portrait? (I am developing for iOS 13)

Comment: read the first line .. it says `In iOS 13 or later, prefer using SF Symbols to represent tasks and modes in your app`