# I want to set an Image to the TabBarItem

Tags: swiftui, tabbar

I try to set an Image for TabBarItem, but the Image always appear with the original size even though I resizable with other size
[image]

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/bars/tab-bars/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I correctly size UITabBarController icons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61642009/how-can-i-correctly-size-uitabbarcontroller-icons)